# Using CASE Statement in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to have a column in a table (not from view)(SQL SERVER 2008) to change according to a value in another column i.e. if I have a column called "DUEDATE" can I have a column called "STATUS" that will change the status to "Now Due" if the "DUEDATE" is > GetDate()? If so how do you add that to a table?

Comment: In best practise, we dont keep a column that can be derived from another.

Comment: I understand but I have created a view to do so but it makes my whole query so slow when I add the Table LEFT JOINED with that View.

Comment: Why would you need to add the table LEFT JOINED to the view? Just create a view that contains all columns from your base table, and add the CASE statement as in my answer below.

Comment: GetDate() is evaluated at the time of execution, Do you need to change the status column to be update when GetDate() and DueDate changed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [DueDate] [date] NULL,
    [ComputedValue]  AS (CASE WHEN [Duedate] > GETDATE() THEN 'Now Due' ELSE '' END)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As this is a non-deterministic column (because of the value of `GETDATE()` that is different every time you use the table), adding it to the table doesn't give you much benefit over returning the same in a select query.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the table and add a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TheTable
ADD Status AS CASE WHEN ...
```

You can't persist it, because it's non-deterministic, so don't add PERSISTED or try to put an index on it.

From an indexing perspective, don't try to query it using WHERE Status = 'whatever', because it will have to consider every row in the table. Instead, use an index on DueDate and WHERE DueDate <= GETDATE()